# missing the database

Tags: database, ms-access, duplicate-data, missing-data

I have a problem with my database which is base on access. when i try to use insert command, all records send to mydatabase.mdb in root folder, but when I want to read from database, records come from another database which is in bin folder.
it cause a big problem because every time I should copy mydatabase.mdb from root folder to bin folder !!!
how I can solve this problem?

P.S.
I use the same connection string in both insert and select command.

```
 public OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=F:\\fanoos\\new work\\C# regester_markaze tebi\\regester\\regester\\bin\\Debug\\Db_reg.mdb");
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your database has linked tables which are pointing to the "other database which is in the bin folder".  Open the database you are connecting to in Access and use the `linked table manager` to see where the linked tables are pointing.  In Access 2010+ (and maybe 2007+) the linked table manager is located on the `External Data` ribbon tab.